# Unable to install httpd-devel on oracle linux 7

Tags: apache

Hi I am trying to install httpd-devel
Following is the output :

```
 sudo yum install httpd-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, ulninfo, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6 for package: httpd-devel-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: httpd-devel-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6.x86_64 (ol7_u4_patch)
           Requires: httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-93.0.1.el7.x86_64 (@7_peo_latest)
               httpd = 2.4.6-93.0.1.el7
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7.x86_64 (ol7_u4_base)
               httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.2.x86_64 (ol7_u4_patch)
               httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.2
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.5.x86_64 (ol7_u4_patch)
               httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.5
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6.x86_64 (ol7_u4_patch)
               httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am not able to resolve this can someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install httpd-devel and its dependency using the below command.

```
yum install httpd*
```

Comment: the above command does not work.. adding * at the end is throwing error yum : no match.. removing * works but the problem is different. If you carefully see the error Requires: httpd = 2.4.6-67.0.1.el7_4.6 and httpd is already installed with httpd-2.4.6-93.0.1.el7.x86_64
Why is it giving error with latest version

Comment: which repo are you using? Looks like repo contains httpd-devel 2.4.6-67 that's why it is trying to install old httpd(2.4.6-67) package. You can use --skip-broken option to install httpd-devel package without dependency.